# How to make ubuntu alert me visually when the battery is critical?

Tags: battery, notification

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and whenever i disconnect it from power supply the **panel battery 
icon** shows me the remaining time at regular interval but it doesnot make an alert when the battery runs out of juice. I am in need of a solution if the battery turns critical it can show me an visual alert, notification or even a sound so that i do not have to monitor the remaining time regularly

Comment: Strange, in my system Ubuntu always shows me a Notification Bubble that the battery is running out of power. The bettery notification should be enabled in your system by default, try reinstalling the packages of NotifyOSD:


sudo apt-get --reinstall install libnotify-bin notify-osd

Comment: WOW ! Let me try it out. Just a min !

Comment: It really worked. I guess my notification system was faulty or something like that thanks for sorting that out ! Is there any way to manupulate this warning method ? just a query !

Comment: Manipulate the NotifyOSD is possible, but I there are just few tweaks, as color changes, time for desappear and placement. I'll make my comment an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: If you want to try any manipulation:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/tweak-notifyosd-notifications-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your NotifyOSD may be corrupted or set to do-not-disturb mode for some reason.

You can reinstall it by entering this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libnotify-bin notify-osd
```

Restart your system and from now on You'll get notifications when the battery is running out of power.