# Critically Low Battery Notification not showing in Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery, notification, notify-osd

Ubuntu is not showing the notification if there is a critically low battery.

I already tried this [reinstalling libnotify-bin notify-osd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231109/how-to-make-ubuntu-alert-me-visually-when-the-battery-is-critical), but that didn't help.

I am using a **dell Inspiron 15 3537** laptop.

Comment: Are other notifications working?

Comment: I am getting other notifications, like notifications from thunder bird

Comment: Ok, so it's the problem of the notification not being fired of, not about it now showing up after that.

Comment: Another question. Do you see the battery indicator in the toolbar?

Comment: Yes I can see the battery indicator.

Comment: What are your energy settings on which limit the mńotification should occur? maybe its just too short before it is empty completely? `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical`

Comment: The output of the command gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical is 3

Comment: The battery icon turns red below 10% but I don't get to see a pop up notification. In my other Laptop it shows a popup notification.

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 10

Comment: @Volodya I changed the value to 10, it's still not showing.

Comment: Ok, then i really don't know. Sorry. Please consider filing a bug by typing in the terminal: ubuntu-bug notify-osd

Answer (score -1):

Please note that by default battery notification should be enabled in your system. Try reinstalling the packages of NotifyOSD which was the source for notification alert in Ubuntu and then check the reported issue, If you have not already tried with NotifyOSD

Command to install NotifyOSD

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libnotify-bin notify-osd
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this doesn't work, already added a link to the question that I have tried this solution